# Go to next item with Find function in Hxd editor

Tags: text, find, text-editor

I have a file that I am trying to find some items in.

Here is an example extract:

> `68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 20 68 6F 77 20 61 72 65 20 79 6F 75 20 68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64`

In my editor it shows  up as:

> `hello world how are you hello world`

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to bring up *Find*.

I entered what I was looking for (hello) in *Search for* and pressed *Search*.  The first result shows up, but my file contains multiple results as you can see above.  How do I move to the next result?

I.e. from the first `hello`, to the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the version of HxD I am using (1.7.7.0), this function is bound to F3. To search in the reverse direction, press Shift+F3.

Alternatively, both options are selectable under 'Search' located on the menu bar.